Problem using Query params to filter MongoDB Go Driver
I'm trying to use the query parameters from a web request to query mongodb. I have successfully parsed the value and added them to bson.d but it returns null.
router.HandleFunc("/route", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    coll := s.MongoDB.Database("the-database").Collection("collection")

    filter := bson.D{}
    for key, value := range r.URL.Query() {
      for _, value := range  value {
        filter = append(filter, bson.E{key, value})
        fmt.Println("filter: ", reflect.TypeOf(value))
      }
    }
 

    cursor, err := coll.Find(context.TODO(), filter1)
    if err != nil {
      w.Write([]byte("Unable find any items."))
    }

    var items []Property
    if err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &items); err != nil {
      w.Write([]byte("Unable find any items."))
     }

    jsonData, err := json.MarshalIndent(items, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    w.Write([]byte(jsonData))
})


However manually adding a bson.E to bson.D successfully returns values. Example:
    filter1 := bson.D{} 
    filter1 = append(filter1, bson.E{"key", 1234})

Comparing the two value using  reflect.DeepEqual(filter, filter1) returns false even though printing values appear to be the same.
// curl "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/route?key=1234"
filter:  [{key 1234}]
TypeOf:  primitive.E // reflect.TypeOf(filter[0])

//filter1 := bson.D{}; filter1 = append(filter1, bson.E{"key", 1234})
filter1:  [{key 1234}] 
TypeOf:  primitive.E  // reflect.TypeOf(filter1[0])

fmt.Print(reflect.DeepEqual(filter, filter1)) // False

Whats the difference between each. Both values appear to be strings but one works and not the other.

value inside your loop will be of type string. When you write bson.E{"key", 1234} here 1234 is of type int. When using string, it will only find documents where that property has a string value, when using int, it will only find documents where that property is a number.

Thanks. Seems obvious now that you pointed it out. Looks like query parameters are always sent as strings. I ended up using the strconv.Atoi() to convert the value. If there's an error I just use the value as is.

As mentioned by icza, The values sent by the query parameters are not integers. In fact, query parameters are always sent as strings and parsing needs to handled server-side. I ended up using strconv.Atoi() to convert the string value to int. If conversion fails I use the value as is. See Convert string to integer type in Go?
    filter := bson.D{}
    for key, value := range r.URL.Query() {
      for _, value := range  value {
        intValue, err := strconv.Atoi(value)
        if err != nil {
          filter = append(filter, bson.E{key, value})
        } else {
          filter = append(filter, bson.E{key, intValue})
        } 
      }
    }

